# How to increase speed level and spawn rate abased on player score

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScrollingObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        //if (GameControl.instance.score > 0)
        //    rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(GameControl.instance.scrollSpeed * GameControl.instance.score, 0);
        //else
         rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(GameControl.instance.scrollSpeed, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (GameControl.instance.score > 5)
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(GameControl.instance.scrollSpeed *3, 0);

        if (GameControl.instance.score > 10)
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(GameControl.instance.scrollSpeed*5, 0);

            if (GameControl.instance.gameOver == true)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Currently you increase the speed **every frame** and for both conditions at the same time ... rather go event based and make your check **ONCE** at the place where the score is actually increased ... You probably would want to go with a kind of states

Comment: yes i make a mistake. i did not know how to rewrite the code . I want the speed level move based on score. I want every time the player successfully pass the +5 score , the level speed will up. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You already seem to have a central Singleton controller storing your values.

So instead of poll checking these values every frame I would rather implement it event based using [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) and an [`event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event)

```
public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    // by default multiplier is 1
    private float multiplier = 1;

    // Configure here whatever your scrollSpeed  is anyway
    [SerializeField] private float _scrollSpeed = 20;

    // A public read-only property which already has the multiplier applied
    public float scrolSpeed => _scrollSpeed * multiplier;

    // the actual score backing field
    private int _score;

    public int score
    {
        // when accessing the score property just return the internal _score value
        get => _score;

        // when assigning a new value to score 
        set
        {
            // update the backing field
            _score = value;
            // also update the multiplier
            // use a base value of 1
            // intentionally use an int division to increase multiplier by 2 for every 5 points
            multiplier = 1 + 2 * score / 5;

            // inform listeners that the score was changed
            onScoreChanged?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    // evnt whih is invoked everytime the score is changed
    public event Action onScoreChanged;

    ...
}
```

and then you simply want to do

```
public class ScrollingObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb2d;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!rb2d) rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.right * GameControl.instance.scrollSpeed;
    }
}
```

if you really need to constantly set the velocity for whatever reason.

Or even better do it all event based and only update the velocity once the score was actually changed:

```
public class ScrollingObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb2d;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!rb2d) rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        // fetch the initial values once immediately
        OnScoreChanged();

        // attach a callback to the score changed event
        GameControl.instance.onScoreChanged += OnScoreChanged;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // be sure to remove callbacks as soon as not needed anymore
        GameControl.instance.onScoreChanged += OnScoreChanged;
    }

    // automatically called once every time the score was changed
    private void OnScoreChanged()
    {
        // update the velocity
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.right * GameControl.instance.scrollSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: okay i got it. But i have one more problem. The game that i recreate is flappy bird game. For the column it doesn't move along with this scroll speed. Column respawn time  did not match with the scroll speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ColumnPool : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int columnPoolSize = 5;
    public GameObject columnPrefab;
    public float spawnRate = 1f;
    public float columnMin = -1.5f;
    public float columnMax = 1.5f;

    private GameObject[] columns;
    private Vector2 objectPoolPosition = new Vector2(-15f, -25f);
    private float timeSinceLastSpawned;
    private float spawnXPosition = 10f;
    private int currentColumn = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        columns = new GameObject[columnPoolSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < columnPoolSize; i++)
        {
            columns[i] = (GameObject)Instantiate(columnPrefab, objectPoolPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       // timeSinceLastSpawned += Time.deltaTime;

        //if (GameControl.instance.score > 5)
        //timeSinceLastSpawned += Time.deltaTime * GameControl.instance.score;

        //// timeSinceLastSpawned += Time.deltaTime;
        //if (GameControl.instance.score % 5 == 0)
        if ((GameControl.instance.score > 1 && GameControl.instance.score % 5 == 0))
        {
            timeSinceLastSpawned += Time.deltaTime;
        }
        //  timeSinceLastSpawned += Time.deltaTime *1.0f;

        //if (GameControl.instance.score > 5)
        //    timeSinceLastSpawned += Time.deltaTime * 2;

        if (GameControl.instance.gameOver == false && timeSinceLastSpawned >= spawnRate)
        {
            timeSinceLastSpawned = 0;
            float spawnYPosition = Random.Range(columnMin, columnMax);
            columns [currentColumn].transform.position = new Vector2(spawnXPosition, spawnYPosition);
            currentColumn++;
            if (currentColumn >= columnPoolSize)
            {
                currentColumn = 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Adding the code is great. But can you edit your answer to explain how you improved the code in the question?